# Scraping a webiste with page limitation

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scrapy

I am trying to scrape https://www.olx.com.eg/en/properties/ listings and there it is showing **200,000+ ads** and I'd like to scrape all 200,000 listings but pagination don't go above 49 pages. I have figure out their api endpoint from where data is coming through.

Api endpoint:

```
'https://search.olx.com.eg/_msearch?filter_path=took%2C*.took%2C*.suggest.*.options.text%2C*.suggest.*.options._source.*%2C*.hits.total.*%2C*.hits.hits._source.*%2C*.hits.hits.highlight.*%2C*.error%2C*.aggregations.*.buckets.key%2C*.aggregations.*.buckets.doc_count%2C*.aggregations.*.buckets.complex_value.hits.hits._source%2C*.aggregations.*.filtered_agg.facet.buckets.key%2C*.aggregations.*.filtered_agg.facet.buckets.doc_count%2C*.aggregations.*.filtered_agg.facet.buckets.complex_value.hits.hits._source'
```

POST data:

```
data = '{"index":"olx-eg-production-ads-ar"}\n{"from":0,"size":0,"track_total_hits":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"category.slug":"properties"}}]}},"aggs":{"category.lvl1.externalID":{"global":{},"aggs":{"filtered_agg":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"category.lvl0.externalID":"138"}}]}},"aggs":{"facet":{"terms":{"field":"category.lvl1.externalID","size":20}}}}}},"location.lvl1":{"global":{},"aggs":{"filtered_agg":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"category.slug":"properties"}},{"term":{"location.lvl0.externalID":"0-1"}}]}},"aggs":{"facet":{"terms":{"field":"location.lvl1.externalID","size":20},"aggs":{"complex_value":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"_source":{"include":["location.lvl1"]}}}}}}}}},"product":{"global":{},"aggs":{"filtered_agg":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"category.slug":"properties"}},{"term":{"product":"featured"}},{"term":{"location.externalID":"0-1"}}]}},"aggs":{"facet":{"terms":{"field":"product","size":20},"aggs":{"complex_value":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"_source":{"include":["product"]}}}}}}}}},"totalProductCount":{"global":{},"aggs":{"filtered_agg":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"category.slug":"properties"}},{"term":{"product":"featured"}}]}},"aggs":{"facet":{"terms":{"field":"product","size":20},"aggs":{"complex_value":{"top_hits":{"size":1,"_source":{"include":["totalProductCount"]}}}}}}}}}}}\n{"index":"olx-eg-production-ads-ar"}\n{"from":0,"size":45,"track_total_hits":200000,"query":{"function_score":{"random_score":{"seed":97},"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"category.slug":"properties"}},{"term":{"product":"featured"}}]}}}},"sort":["_score"]}\n{"index":"olx-eg-production-ads-ar"}\n{"from":10045,"size":45,"track_total_hits":200000,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"category.slug":"properties"}}]}},"sort":[{"timestamp":{"order":"desc"}},{"id":{"order":"desc"}}]}\n'
```

Problem is even this elasticsearch endpoint have a limitation of 10000 listings when I try to increase the `from` value in POST data it throws:

```
{"message":"[query_phase_execution_exception] Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10045]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting.","error":{"status":500}
```

I'd like to get all the 200,000 listings, any work around?

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import requests


class OlxScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "olx-scraper"

    custom_settings = {
        "FEED_FORMAT": "csv",
        "FEED_URI": "olx_eg_property_listing.csv",
        "LOG_FILE": "olx_eg.log",
    }

    listing_endpoint = "https://search.olx.com.eg/_msearch?filter_path=took%2C*.took%2C*.suggest.*.options.text%2C*.suggest.*.options._source.*%2C*.hits.total.*%2C*.hits.hits._source.*%2C*.hits.hits.highlight.*%2C*.error%2C*.aggregations.*.buckets.key%2C*.aggregations.*.buckets.doc_count%2C*.aggregations.*.buckets.complex_value.hits.hits._source%2C*.aggregations.*.filtered_agg.facet.buckets.key%2C*.aggregations.*.filtered_agg.facet.buckets.doc_count%2C*.aggregations.*.filtered_agg.facet.buckets.complex_value.hits.hits._source"

    headers = {
        "authority": "search.olx.com.eg",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-language": "en,ru;q=0.9",
        "authorization": "Basic b2x4LWVnLXByb2R1Y3Rpb24tc2VhcmNoOn1nNDM2Q0R5QDJmWXs2alpHVGhGX0dEZjxJVSZKbnhL",
        "content-type": "application/x-ndjson",
        "origin": "https://www.olx.com.eg",
        "referer": "https://www.olx.com.eg/",
        "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Yandex";v="22"',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Linux"',
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.143 YaBrowser/22.5.0.1879 (beta) Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
    }

    data = '{{"index":"olx-eg-production-ads-ar"}}\n{{"from":0,"size":0,"track_total_hits":false,"query":{{"bool":{{"must":[{{"term":{{"category.slug":"properties"}}}}]}}}},"aggs":{{"category.lvl1.externalID":{{"global":{{}},"aggs":{{"filtered_agg":{{"filter":{{"bool":{{"must":[{{"term":{{"category.lvl0.externalID":"138"}}}}]}}}},"aggs":{{"facet":{{"terms":{{"field":"category.lvl1.externalID","size":20}}}}}}}}}}}},"location.lvl1":{{"global":{{}},"aggs":{{"filtered_agg":{{"filter":{{"bool":{{"must":[{{"term":{{"category.slug":"properties"}}}},{{"term":{{"location.lvl0.externalID":"0-1"}}}}]}}}},"aggs":{{"facet":{{"terms":{{"field":"location.lvl1.externalID","size":20}},"aggs":{{"complex_value":{{"top_hits":{{"size":1,"_source":{{"include":["location.lvl1"]}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}},"product":{{"global":{{}},"aggs":{{"filtered_agg":{{"filter":{{"bool":{{"must":[{{"term":{{"category.slug":"properties"}}}},{{"term":{{"product":"featured"}}}},{{"term":{{"location.externalID":"0-1"}}}}]}}}},"aggs":{{"facet":{{"terms":{{"field":"product","size":20}},"aggs":{{"complex_value":{{"top_hits":{{"size":1,"_source":{{"include":["product"]}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}},"totalProductCount":{{"global":{{}},"aggs":{{"filtered_agg":{{"filter":{{"bool":{{"must":[{{"term":{{"category.slug":"properties"}}}},{{"term":{{"product":"featured"}}}}]}}}},"aggs":{{"facet":{{"terms":{{"field":"product","size":20}},"aggs":{{"complex_value":{{"top_hits":{{"size":1,"_source":{{"include":["totalProductCount"]}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}\n{{"index":"olx-eg-production-ads-ar"}}\n{{"from":45,"size":0,"track_total_hits":200000,"query":{{"function_score":{{"random_score":{{"seed":97}},"query":{{"bool":{{"must":[{{"term":{{"category.slug":"properties"}}}},{{"term":{{"product":"featured"}}}}]}}}}}}}},"sort":["_score"]}}\n{{"index":"olx-eg-production-ads-ar"}}\n{{"from":{},"size":45,"track_total_hits":200000,"query":{{"bool":{{"must":[{{"term":{{"category.slug":"properties"}}}}]}}}},"sort":[{{"timestamp":{{"order":"desc"}}}},{{"id":{{"order":"desc"}}}}]}}\n'

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(0, 100045):
            pg = i + 45
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.listing_endpoint,
                method="POST",
                headers=self.headers,
                body=self.data.format(pg),
                callback=self.parse_links,
            )

    def parse_links(self, response):
        try:
            listing_data = response.json()["responses"][2]["hits"]["hits"]
        except:
            listing_data = response.json()["responses"][1]["hits"]["hits"]

        for listing in listing_data:
            listing_id = listing["_source"]["externalID"]
            listing_url = "https://www.olx.com.eg/en/ad/" + listing_id

            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=listing_url,
                headers=self.headers,
                callback=self.parse_details,
                meta={"listing_url": listing_url},
            )

    def parse_details(self, response):
        item = {}
        reference_id = response.css("div._171225da::text").get().replace("Ad id ", "")
        sub_detail_list = response.css("div._676a547f ::text").extract()

        item["URL"] = response.meta.get("listing_url")
        try:
            item["Breadcrumb"] = (
                response.css("li._8c543153 ::text")[4].get()
                + "/"
                + response.css("li._8c543153 ::text")[3].get()
                + "/"
                + response.css("li._8c543153 ::text")[2].get()
                + "/"
                + response.css("li._8c543153 ::text")[1].get()
                + "/"
                + response.css("li._8c543153 ::text").get()
            )
        except:
            item["Breadcrumb"] = (
                +response.css("li._8c543153 ::text")[3].get()
                + "/"
                + response.css("li._8c543153 ::text")[2].get()
                + "/"
                + response.css("li._8c543153 ::text")[1].get()
                + "/"
                + response.css("li._8c543153 ::text").get()
            )

        item["Price"] = response.css("span._56dab877 ::text").get()
        item["Title"] = response.css("h1.a38b8112::text").get()
        item["Type"] = response.css("div.b44ca0b3 ::text")[1].get()
        item["Bedrooms"] = response.css("span.c47715cd::text").get()
        try:
            item["Bathrooms"] = response.css("span.c47715cd::text")[1].get()
        except:
            item["Bathrooms"] = ""
        try:
            item["Area"] = response.css("span.c47715cd::text")[2].get()
        except:
            for sub in sub_detail_list:
                if "Area (m²)" in sub_detail_list:
                    item["Area"] = sub_detail_list[
                        sub_detail_list.index("Area (m²)") + 1
                    ]
                else:
                    item["Area"] = ""
        item["Location"] = response.css("span._8918c0a8::text").get()
        try:
            if response.css("div.b44ca0b3 ::text")[18].get() == "Compound":
                item["Compound"] = response.css("div.b44ca0b3 ::text")[19].get()
            elif response.css("div.b44ca0b3 ::text")[16].get() == "Compound":
                item["Compound"] = response.css("div.b44ca0b3 ::text")[17].get()
        except:
            item["Compound"] = ""
        item["seller"] = response.css("span._261203a9._2e82a662::text").getall()[1]
        member_since = response.css("span._34a7409b ::text")[1].get()
        if member_since == "Cars for Sale":
            item["Seller_member_since"] = response.css("span._34a7409b ::text").get()
        if "Commercial ID: " in member_since:
            item["Seller_member_since"] = response.css("span._34a7409b ::text")[2].get()
        else:
            item["Seller_member_since"] = member_since
        res = requests.get(
            f"https://www.olx.com.eg/api/listing/{reference_id}/contactInfo/"
        )
        item["Seller_phone_number"] = res.json()["mobile"]
        item["Description"] = (
            response.css("div._0f86855a ::text").get().replace("\n", "")
        )
        item["Amenities"] = ",".join(response.css("div._27f9c8ac ::text").extract())
        item["Reference"] = reference_id
        item["Listed_date"] = response.css("span._8918c0a8 ::text")[1].get()
        item["Level"] = ""
        item["Payment_option"] = ""
        item["Delivery_term"] = ""
        item["Furnished"] = ""
        item["Delivery_date"] = ""
        item["Down_payment"] = ""

        for sub_detail in sub_detail_list:
            if "Level" in sub_detail_list:
                item["Level"] = sub_detail_list[sub_detail_list.index("Level") + 1]
            if "Payment Option" in sub_detail_list:
                item["Payment_option"] = sub_detail_list[
                    sub_detail_list.index("Payment Option") + 1
                ]
            if "Delivery Term" in sub_detail_list:
                item["Delivery_term"] = sub_detail_list[
                    sub_detail_list.index("Delivery Term") + 1
                ]
            if "Furnished" in sub_detail_list:
                item["Furnished"] = sub_detail_list[
                    sub_detail_list.index("Furnished") + 1
                ]
            if "Delivery Date" in sub_detail_list:
                item["Delivery_date"] = sub_detail_list[
                    sub_detail_list.index("Delivery Date") + 1
                ]
            if "Down Payment" in sub_detail_list:
                item["Down_payment"] = sub_detail_list[
                    sub_detail_list.index("Down Payment") + 1
                ]

        item["Image_url"] = response.css("picture._219b7e0a ::attr(srcset)")[1].get()

        yield item


# main driver
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run scrapper
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(OlxScraper)
    process.start()
```

How to overcome this 10000 limit? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can apply filters on the listing so that the number of returned items is lesser. You can apply the combination of filters as well. For e.g. using categories and location to filter the data.

Comment: categories itself contains more than 10k listings so if I apply the combination filters too it will also restrict me to under 10k.